# How to deploy WildFly locally?

Tags: java, spring-boot, localhost

I have war file with my Spring Boot project(REST API). I run this WAR in WildFly locally (`http://localhost:8080`).

Is it any way to send request from another device that use the same wifi as PC where this WAR is deployed? For example I need to send request from my mobile phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible, but... Either other device ip must be in the same network (does not matter through WiFi or Ethernet) or there must be a gateway/router to route external requests to your machine. Anyway address from other device will no be `localhost`, but your machine ip or DNS name